# How can I call useEffect to re-render upon a particular state change

Tags: reactjs, rendering, addeventlistener, use-effect, use-state

I need the first useEffect below to re-render upon a change to the grid state. Specifically, I need the useEffect containing `initializeGrid()` to re-render once a change of state is registered for `grid` inside the changeWall function when I reassigned one of the grid object's values to true. I need this change to immediately re-render that `initializeGrid()` function

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";


const Pathfind = () => {

  const [grid, setGrid] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    initializeGrid();
  }, []);

  const initializeGrid = () => {

    grid = new Array(X);

    for (let i = 0; i < Y; i++) {
      grid[i] = new Array(Y);
    }

    setGrid(grid);

  };

  let isMouseDown = false;

  function changeWall(e) {
    let id = e.target.id;
    grid[id.y][id.x].isWall = true;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
      isMouseDown = true;

      document.onmouseup = () => {
        isMouseDown = false;
        document.removeEventListener("mouseover", changeWall);
      };

      if (mouseIsDown) {
        document.addEventListener("mouseover", changeWall);
      }

    });
  }, []);

 };

export default Pathfind;
```

Comment: first of all your code looks weird, i dont think u can use react hooks outside functional component, also no render ?

Comment: If you run your initializeGrid function in any grid change its create new grid without your changes and assigned this grid with set state so you will not see any change

Comment: I see a risk of a loop, if you want the useEffect to react to a change in the same property it is triggering a change on.
I would seuggest you only use useEffect to react to changes outside the component.
You probably wants to run the initializeGrid instead. In that way the grid is set when the component first is initiated, and reset when you need to change grid. Pass the new values to the initializeGrid instead of directly to setGrid.
As stated above you have some missing code in your example.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The `grid` state is const, so attempting `grid = new Array(X);` will throw an error in `initializeGrid`. Perhaps you meant to declare a new variable to initialize/update state with.

```
const grid = new Array(X);
```

## Answer

Use a second piece of state to indicate a "wall" was changed. Initial state of `true` will allow the `initializeGrid` function to run on the initial component mounting render.

```
const [wallChanged, setWallChanged] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  if (wallChanged) {
    setWallChanged(false);
    initializeGrid();
  }
}, [wallChanged]);
```

Set wall changed state in the handler to trigger re-initialization.

```
function changeWall(e) {
  const { id } = e.target;
  grid[id.y][id.x].isWall = true; // *
  setWallChanged(true);
}
```

* ***Note:** Be aware that `grid[id.y][id.x].isWall = true;` is a state mutation.* Without much other context though I can't say for sure if this is an actual issue, but it is definitely a code smell.

Actually, since `initializeGrid` resets the grid state completely, this is probably not an issue, and really, the `grid[id.y][id.x].isWall = true;` line may not be completely unnecessary with the `wallChanged` state "flag".

A much simpler solution may just be to invoke `initializeGrid` directly in the handler. No extra state and the `grid` state is updated and component rerenders at least 1 render cycle earlier than my previous solution.

```
function changeWall(e) {
  initializeGrid();
}
```